# How to make hash code verification on payment in magento 2

Tags: magento2, security, payment-gateway, payment-banktransfer

```
  <?php


    namespace PayUIndia\Payu\Model;

    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionInterface;

    class Payu extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod {

        const PAYMENT_PAYU_CODE = 'payu';
        const ACC_BIZ = 'payubiz';
        const ACC_MONEY = 'payumoney';

        protected $_code = self::PAYMENT_PAYU_CODE;

        /**
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface 
         */
        protected $_urlBuilder;
        protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array(
            'AFN', 'ALL', 'DZD', 'ARS', 'AUD', 'AZN', 'BSD', 'BDT', 'BBD',
            'BZD', 'BMD', 'BOB', 'BWP', 'BRL', 'GBP', 'BND', 'BGN', 'CAD',
            'CLP', 'CNY', 'COP', 'CRC', 'HRK', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'DOP', 'XCD',
            'EGP', 'EUR', 'FJD', 'GTQ', 'HKD', 'HNL', 'HUF', 'INR', 'IDR',
            'ILS', 'JMD', 'JPY', 'KZT', 'KES', 'LAK', 'MMK', 'LBP', 'LRD',
            'MOP', 'MYR', 'MVR', 'MRO', 'MUR', 'MXN', 'MAD', 'NPR', 'TWD',
            'NZD', 'NIO', 'NOK', 'PKR', 'PGK', 'PEN', 'PHP', 'PLN', 'QAR',
            'RON', 'RUB', 'WST', 'SAR', 'SCR', 'SGF', 'SBD', 'ZAR', 'KRW',
            'LKR', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'SYP', 'THB', 'TOP', 'TTD', 'TRY', 'UAH',
            'AED', 'USD', 'VUV', 'VND', 'XOF', 'YER'
        );

        private $checkoutSession;

        /**
         * 
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory
         * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
         * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger
         * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
         * @param array $data
         */
          public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
            \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
            \PayUIndia\Payu\Helper\Payu $helper,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession      

        ) {
            $this->helper = $helper;
            $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
            $this->httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $registry,
                $extensionFactory,
                $customAttributeFactory,
                $paymentData,
                $scopeConfig,
                $logger
            );

        }

        public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode) {
            if (!in_array($currencyCode, $this->_supportedCurrencyCodes)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function getRedirectUrl() {
            return $this->helper->getUrl($this->getConfigData('redirect_url'));
        }

        public function getReturnUrl() {
            return $this->helper->getUrl($this->getConfigData('return_url'));
        }

        public function getCancelUrl() {
            return $this->helper->getUrl($this->getConfigData('cancel_url'));
        }

        /**
         * Return url according to environment
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCgiUrl() {
            $env = $this->getConfigData('environment');
            if ($env === 'production') {
                return $this->getConfigData('production_url');
            }
            return $this->getConfigData('sandbox_url');
        }

        public function buildCheckoutRequest() {
            $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
            $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress();

            $params = array();
            $params["key"] = $this->getConfigData("merchant_key");
            if ($this->getConfigData('account_type') == self::ACC_MONEY) {
                $params["service_provider"] = $this->getConfigData("service_provider");
            }
            $params["txnid"] = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
            $params["amount"] = round($order->getBaseGrandTotal(), 2);
            $params["productinfo"] = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();
            $params["firstname"] = $billing_address->getFirstName();
            $params["lastname"] = $billing_address->getLastname();
            $params["city"]                 = $billing_address->getCity();
            $params["state"]                = $billing_address->getRegion();
            $params["zip"]                  = $billing_address->getPostcode();
            $params["country"]              = $billing_address->getCountryId();
            $params["email"] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
            $params["phone"] = $billing_address->getTelephone();
            $params["curl"] = $this->getCancelUrl();
            $params["furl"] = $this->getReturnUrl();
            $params["surl"] = $this->getReturnUrl();

            $params["hash"] = $this->generatePayuHash($params['txnid'],
                    $params['amount'], $params['productinfo'], $params['firstname'],
                    $params['email']);

            return $params;
        }

        public function generatePayuHash($txnid, $amount, $productInfo, $name,
                $email) {
            $SALT = $this->getConfigData('salt');

            $posted = array(
                'key' => $this->getConfigData("merchant_key"),
                'txnid' => $txnid,
                'amount' => $amount,
                'productinfo' => $productInfo,
                'firstname' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
            );

            $hashSequence = 'key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10';

            $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
            $hash_string = '';
            foreach ($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
                $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
                $hash_string .= '|';
            }
            $hash_string .= $SALT;
            return strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
        }



        //validate response
        public function validateResponse($returnParams) {
            if ($returnParams['status'] == 'pending' || $returnParams['status'] == 'failure') {
                return false;
            }
            if ($returnParams['key'] != $this->getConfigData("merchant_key") ) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public function postProcessing(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
                \Magento\Framework\DataObject $payment, $response) {

            $payment->setTransactionId($response['txnid']);
            $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo('payu_mihpayid',
                    $response['mihpayid']);
            $payment->setAdditionalInformation('payu_order_status', 'approved');
            $payment->addTransaction(TransactionInterface::TYPE_ORDER);
            $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
            $payment->place();
            $order->setStatus('processing');
            $order->save();
        }

    }
```

How to add reverse hash verification.